# changing rootviewcontroller of a UINavigationController which is in storyboard while its initialised

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UINavigationController` controller in the story board which is the entry point,whose class is  `MyNavigationController`.
I have not assigned the `rootviewcontroller` to the `UINavigationController`, from  the story board ,but want to assign the same from `MyNavigationController`,From some initialize methods
Please help me how to do that or is it impossible?.

Comment: your question is not clear, else use initiatewithidentifier, else to find the top controller

Comment: Is it not possible by overriding any methods in 'MyNavigationController'?

Comment: r u using stroyboard or xib and r u worked in objective - c or swift

Comment: I am using storyboard and objective c

Comment: Thanks Anbu.Karthik for the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**choice-1**

you can Identify your Stroryboard ID and set as Root

[image]

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginSignupVC"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
```

**Choice-2**

the Initial View COntroller automatically identify your Root controller

[image]

you can Identify your Stroryboard ID on your viewcontroller using Attribute

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyNavigationController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginSignupVC"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
```

**Choice-3**

xcode --> Menu -> editor -> embedIn -> NavigationController

[image]

you can get like following output

[image]

it find automatically your root controller

Comment: Any possibility to do that  `MyNavigationController ` ?

Comment: `MyNavigationController` as mentioned in the question

Comment: I am exploring the second option you mentioned in the answer ,if that alone can be done in code.

Comment: then you can identify easily , use Choice -1

Comment: Yes that I tried and works ,but just the second option alone to code.Please bear with me if that doesn't make sense.But just wanted assigning rootviewcontroller mentioned in the second step alone to be done via code

Comment: @rajeshsukumaran -- tamil la solraen k, second one than unoda project la iruku, atha **Storyboard ID` use panni call panni work panina nee kaetathu work aagum , atha than choice one la solirukaen

Answer (score 0):

So you subclassed `UINavigationController`, if I understand correctly and you want it to be initialised with a given view controller.

You can override `init` in `MyNavigationController` and call `[super initWithRootViewController:myRootViewController]`, where myRootViewController is an instance of a `UIViewController` or its subclass.

You would then use `MyNavigationController` as such:

```
MyNavigationController *myNavigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] init];
```

For more info, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithRootViewController:

Comment: I don't want to use           
`MyNavigationController *myNavigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] init];`
Its on the story board and is the entry point ,just want to assign or assign the `rootviewcontroller` alone

Comment: Young from my phone here. Have you seen setViewControllers method?

Comment: You can call [myNavigationController setViewCobtrollers:@[myRootViewController]];

Comment: your `init` method should look like this:

`- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self setViewCobtrollers:@[myRootViewController]];
    
    return self;
}`

sorry about the formatting

Comment: Already tried .This doesn't gets called,I think initwithcoder will be called

Comment: Probably, if you have it in storyboard. So override that function and with what I've posted before.