# LaunchScreen.storyboard not opening Main.storyboard Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have just started to develop a new application using Swift (newbie). I have

1. LaunchScreen.storyboard with just a image of my splash screen
2. I have a Main.storyboard with a `Navigation Controller` connected to two `segues`, Home and Registration.
3. In the `ViewController.swift`, inside the `viewDidLoad` I am deciding which segue to call
4. My `Main.Storyboard` does not have a `rootViewController`, I need to decide which `viewController` to display at **run time**.

   ```
   if (Settings.hasRegistrationCompleted()) {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home", sender: nil)
   } else {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "Registration", sender: nil)
   }
   ```

My questions

1. I put a breakpoint on the first line `if (Settings.has` and the breakpoint never reaches here
2. LaunchScreen lasts only for 2 seconds (tested on my Simulator) how do I increase it

**EDIT**

I have `Main` set as the `Main Interface` on my project. I did a `Clean` build and tried again, did not work.

Also below is the Main.Storyboard

[image]

Comment: pardon here `only for 2 seconds (tested on my Simulator) how do I increase it`

Comment: When I launch my app the SplashScreen (launch) shows for about 2 seconds and the app then goes BLACK..

Comment: can you show your Storyboard scene

Comment: it means the initial VC not set properly

Comment: can you please try it in willAppear ?

Comment: @Priyal - issue not in conditon , problem in before

Comment: The LaunchScreen is handled by the OS, if you want a longer duration LaunchScreen you can make a `ViewController` for that.

Comment: Black screen appear coz  your initial arrow point no assign for the rootVC

Comment: have you set Main.storyboard as you main interface ?

Comment: Yes, I have set my Main interface on the project. Did a clean build too.

Comment: @Siddharth did any of the answers help ?

Comment: Yes, the root cause is that I dont have a rootViewController in my Main.Storyboard. I need to programmatically set that based on if I am logged in or not. I am crippled by learning `swift` now, hence taking a bit of time for adding that code into ` func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`. I am working on it actively, once I finish it I'll report back.

Comment: @Siddharth - check I updated the answer

Comment: Mr Downvoter, Please review my question again. Some edits have been made to make the question more clearer and better. A -1 is a wrong impression to good question. Please help keep SO clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in here two things you need to identify

**first**

check your storyboard name `Main.storyboard` are attached properly in your `Target -> general -> Deployment Info -> main Interface`, for e.g like this

[image]

**second**

check your Intial VC connected with navigation Controller and ensure your Initial VC as Root controller

[image]

**update answer**

initially set  Stroryboard ID and for each VC

[image]

there after change the Root controller in appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController: UIViewController?
     if (Settings.hasRegistrationCompleted()) {
     rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
    }else
     {
         rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationVC")
    }
     let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController!)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigation
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Comment: @Siddharth - then check condition in appdelegate didfinishlaunch, else where you struck

Comment: Yeah, looking into that now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Siddharth - in this `(Settings.hasRegistrationCompleted()) { use NSuserdefault` i will  modify the answer

Comment: @Siddharth - see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944909/changing-rootviewcontroller-of-a-uinavigationcontroller-which-is-in-storyboard-w

Comment: @Siddharth - sorry my bro, if your question is clear, we can give the answer is clearly else its takes some delay for identify bz its occurs in many scenarios, any way happy to hear, if my answer s useful accept

Comment: :) I did not know that a `StoryBoard` needs a `rootViewController`, I did not even know what a `rootViewController` was. Thanks I know better now. I have modified my question with a `Point 4` to help **SO** keep more clearer questions. Please do let me know if I can further improve my question.

Comment: @Siddharth - no need bro, now its clear on your question , rootViewController is nothing but its a initial VC, storyboard always need initalVC, else its shows BlackVC

Comment: @NitinGohel - I agree your answer bro, may be the questioner needs the excat answer

Comment: thanks @NitinGohel your hint was bang on with the information provided. Crippled by not knowing swift, Anbu provided me with the exact code taht needs to be at that place (`AppDelegate`) and saved me close to 2 hours :).

Answer (score 1):

You can also Subclass `UINavigationController` and set it to the storyboard. Remove the segues (you don't need them)

Then

```
class ViewController: UINavigationController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (Settings.hasRegistrationCompleted()) {
      let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
      self.setViewControllers([homeVC!], animated: false)
    }
    else {
      let regVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationVC")
      self.setViewControllers([regVC!], animated: false)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I have these 2 set correctly. Thanks for taking the time to present it clearly.

Comment: @Siddharth do try this

Comment: I tried calling this is the `viewDidLoad` but it did not work. I had to fix it by calling `self.window?.rootViewController = navigation` in the `AppDelegate` as recommended by @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: To do this you have to change class of navigation controller and remove segue. Here is a [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7qj0uhk7q7wto1/SwiftTest.zip?dl=0) do check it

Comment: What are hte advantages of this method over the AppDelegate method ?

Comment: This is another way of doing it (Seeing at you problem initially). The app delegate is the right way to decide where to move.

Answer (score 1):

There you must be have One `View-Controller` as a `RootVieController` of your `NavigationController` and it must be initialize with arow like following screenshot. From The Login you need to segue to two View Controller.

Like Following

[image]

So you need to check in `LoginViewController` that you are already logged in or not. Or you can segue to register

Comment: But I dont want a main controller. I want to decide which one to open programmatically.

Comment: but you must be set a rootVC how ever you are create as a programeticuly then you need to assisng as a self.window rootvc with navigation.

Comment: @Siddharth - ask your question in clearly , else we give the answer in assumption

Comment: if you can check user is logged in already in appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then you also set by window.rootViewController = rootController at app delegate one

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik what is not clear in my question. Please state that. I'll edit it immediately for complete clarity. Please note (I am a newbie at iOS, but have 20 years of programming experience)

Comment: see the steps is: first you have a initial root for the app start. second you must be have a vc for check is register or not. if not then register then login so you must  be have login page. and from there you can set seque and show it. other way you can add code at app delegate to set programeticuly rootviewcontrolelr but there you also need to set root first then eque. there is a NO MEAN HOW MUCH EXP in programming but must be have a flow...of work

Comment: @Siddharth - cool my bro, are you seen the answers, if you added in initally  me, nithin and kumar un necessary added the answers here, ok lets we conitue your topic , in here in this `if (Settings.hasRegistrationCompleted()) {` use `NSuserdefault`, and check your condition in appdelegate , based on Condition set your root controller

Comment: @Siddharth as i mention you you that NavigationController must he have a RootViewController. you must be add rootFirst otherwise you always get black screen